# code analysis warning to make a collection read only

Tags: c#, .net, code-analysis

I am getting a warning as below:

> CA2227 : Microsoft.Usage : Change `AddionalUserList` to be read-only by
>   removing the property setter

My code won't allow me to make read only. I am setting this property by an AJAX call.
can any one tel me how to get rid of this warning?

Comment: Some context would be good. The analizers not always stupid :) Where do you store this object? In session or static variable?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the warning in the code analysis or error view and add a exclusion. It will add a annotation either in the file next to the property or in a global suppression file depending on which option you choose which will prevent the warning from showing up.